# How to set character limits to a textbox that is read-only?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, windows-forms-designer

I am creating a calculator app in visual studio. I created some buttons in windows form that will input numbers in a textbox. Since the input did not came from a keyborad, the MaxLength properties is not working for me. I set the textbox to read only so that the user can only input through the buttons. How can I set the character limits (characters because I add "," in thousands, ten thousands etc. I only allow 12 digits + the 3 commas making a total of 15 characters in a textbox) that in a textbox that is filled with buttons?

Comment: You should mention (with a tag) how you are building your app (Windows Forms, WPF, Xamarin,...). You are writing the app, including the button handlers. You can do whatever you want. Just wrote some code to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom TextBox that ensures the text is never larger than the MaxLength property.

```
class RestrictedTextBox : TextBox
{
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value.Length > MaxLength)
                base.Text = value.Substring(0, MaxLength);
            else
                base.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really need more information as to what type of app your using to build the calculator like WPF/Winforms/Web.

Since your using a UI element, and this is strictly a UI display you could do this in the code behind file for the UI page.

You'll need to check the length of the textbox to determine if the length is under whatever your limit is, and if so then add the button's value to the the text property for that textbox

something like the following

```
If (textbox.Text.Length < 15)
    textbox.Text += Button.Content.Value
```

As for inserting the commas you'll again need to check the length and can insert a comma at the correct spot when needed.

Comment: Sorry. I am creating the app in Winforms (.NET)